# TypeScript typings for a class which is new-able and callable

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-definitions

I'm currently editing the typings for [Duplexify](https://github.com/mafintosh/duplexify).

As you can see in [Duplexify's source code](https://github.com/mafintosh/duplexify/blob/master/index.js#L33), `Duplexify` can be either be a function which returns a new `Duplexify` instance, or a constructor.

In [Duplexify's current typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/duplexify/index.d.ts#L11), `Duplexify` is considered an interface rather than a class, which is incorrect but enables defining it as either a function or a constructor.

Is it possible to define `Duplexify` as a class with a constructor (therefore `new`-able) and as a function (therefore callable) at the same time?

**EDIT**: I found [the following article](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files) in TypeScript's documentations. If you look under "New + callable methods" and "Single Complex Object in External Modules" you'd see that it pretty much answers my question, the only problem is that trying to implement that I had the following error:

Implementation:

```
import * as stream from "stream";

declare function Duplexify(writable?: stream.Writable, readable?: stream.Readable, streamOptions?: stream.DuplexOptions): Duplexify;
declare module Duplexify {
    var obj: (writable?: stream.Writable, readable?: stream.Readable, streamOptions?: stream.DuplexOptions) => Duplexify;
}
interface Duplexify extends stream.Duplex {
    new(writable?: stream.Writable, readable?: stream.Readable, streamOptions?: stream.DuplexOptions): Duplexify;

    readonly destroyed: boolean;

    setWritable(writable: stream.Writable): void;
    setReadable(readable: stream.Readable): void;
    destroy(): void;
}

export = Duplexify;
```

Usage:

```
import { Duplexify } from 'duplexify';
const d: Duplexify = new Duplexify(); // errors
```

Errors are:

> [ts] Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.

and:

> [ts] 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's nothing "incorrect" about the declared types being an interface as opposed to a class.  The entire TypeScript standard library is [full](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.5.3/lib/lib.d.ts#L850) of [places](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.5.3/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L31) where class constructors are declared as interfaces.

Comment: True, it's not incorrect, it's just not informative enough. Also, the problem with declaring `Duplexify` as an interface is that interfaces cannot have static members, which Duplexify has. Also, Duplexify shouldn't be implementable but extendable.

Comment: If you look at the standard library, they have pairs of interfaces: one for the instance type, which contains the instance methods and properties,  and one the constructor type, which contains the constructor methods and the static methods and properties.  

But your point about using `extends` instead of `implements` is interesting.  I'm not sure how to handle that.

Comment: I'm aware of the `interface XConstructor { new(...) }` and `interface X { }` definition style, but it doesn't suit my needs for this package's definitions.

Comment: Note that the Typescript documentation is now available [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html). Any documentation which may have been available on CodePlex is probably at least 3 years out of date.

Comment: I know that, but it seemed useful at the time of asking the question. Some things are just not possible with TypeScript, such as declaring such class.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to declare a type signature for a function that can be both instantiated and invoked:

```js
type Instance = { b: number }
type F = { (arg: string): Instance } & { new (arg: string): Instance }
```

A reference of type `F` can be both instantiated and invoked:

```js
declare const f: F

// Both of the following will compile
(new f("foo")).b
f("foo").b
```

Comment: That seems nice but sadly it doesn't help because `Instance` and `F` are `interface`s, and I need `Duplexify` to be a class.

Also, it has a static function which cannot be contained in any type besides class, and it extends `stream.Duplex` which is a class itself, therefore there's no sense in defining `Duplexify` as an interface.

Comment: Interfaces and classes are totally different universes of things. Every class *has* an type, i.e. TypeScript's representation of it. The class itself is a value, for which the type is described by you using type annotations (interfaces, `type` declarations), or inferred from the value expression by the TypeScript type checker. So an interface/type declaration is always used as a complement to a class (or for that matter any other JS value), not as a substitute.

Comment: I'm aware of that, which is exactly why I can't use your solution which suggests using interfaces. I need Duplexify to be defined as a class therefore `new`able **and** extendable instead of implementable, and also for it to be callable.

Comment: @AmitB. Duplexify can be defined as a class *and* described using a type declaration. They are not mutually exclusive alternatives; they are of necessity complementary.